# Scrollview jumps to updated imageview

Tags: android, scrollview

At the end of my scrollview I have a button. With onclick I update a imageview at the top of the scrollview. (Image.SetImageResource(R.drawable.xxx))

After updating the imageview the scrollview 'jumps' on to the ImageView.

How can I stop the jumping of scrollview over the imageview?

Answer (score 1):

try to set this in the xml file to your ImageView:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

because, after you seeting a new ImageResource to your ImageView, the Imageview get the focus and this want your application to show.